# Salesforce DX - how to set default devhub if I missed the -d option when connecting to devhub

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

If I missed the -d option when using sfdx force:auth:web:login, is there a way to reset it as default devhub afterwards? I searched through the document but didn't see any.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use `sf config set target-dev-hub=me@myhub.org`.
You can use the additional -g parameter if you want to set it globally.

The related doc is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_config.htm#cli_reference_set), in addition to using `sf config set -h`.

You can also set afterwards your default Scratch Org using `sf config set target-dev-hub=me@my.org`.

Answer (score 7):

With the new Salesforce CLI, use this command:

```
sf config set target-dev-hub=me@myhub.org
```